# Python 3.6 Statistics module - NameError: name 'statistics' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics

While learning to use "statistics module" in python 3.6 I am facing the following error: 
NameError: name 'statistics' is not defined
I am just testing statistics basic functions which should return mean, median, mode, stdev, variance.
I am new to Python and I can't find where the error is.

Code:

```
from statistics import *

example_list = [5,2,5,6,1,2,6,7,2,6,3,5,5]

x = statistics.mean(example_list)
print(x)

y = statistics.median(example_list)
print(y)

z = statistics.mode(example_list)
print(z)

a = statistics.stdev(example_list)
print(a)

b = statistics.variance(example_list)
print(b)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I do this in IDLE, all works as expected.

```
>>> from statistics import *
>>> example_list = [5,2,5,6,1,2,6,7,2,6,3,5,5]
>>> x = mean(example_list)
>>> x
4.230769230769231
```

So I don't get the error you report at `x = mean(example_list)`.

You haven't reported your stack trace (*why not?*) so it's not possible for me to tell, but I suspect you have named your test program `statistics.py`, and that is hiding the real `statistics` module.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you. I still don't understand how naming the script statistics.py will hide all function's module however when I change this to stats.py it all works.

Comment: The `statistics` module lives in a file called `statistics. py`. Having your own module of the same name in the local folder takes precedence.

Answer (score 2):

[`"from" module "import" *`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) brings in all the names defined in `__all__` if that exists and all names except for those starting with an underscore if `__all__` doesn't exist.

You don't need to qualify the names imported (that is, prefix them with `statistics`). Just used them directly, `median`, `mode`, `stdev`, `variance`.

Comment: Maybe it's worth putting in the answer that `from something import *` is really not a great idea, and a better way to fix this would be to `import statistics` and keep the rest of the code as it is?

Comment: Thank for you answer. I got the same NameError 'mean' is not defined after removing 'statistics' prefix